# MSXML 6, User/PW Auth, ResolveExternals

Tags: msxml, msxml6

If one must load and parse an XML resource from a user/PW-protected URL you cannot just use an MSXML DOM.Load() as far as I can tell.  There is no place to specify the credentials.

Yet if you use XMLHTTPRequest to obtain and parse the resource into a DOM (via its .responseXML property) you have nowhere to specify a value for the .resolveExternals property.

This more or less works out when you use MSXML 3, 4, (or even 5) where it defaults to True, however in MSXML 6 it defaults to False:

[resolveExternals Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762283%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> In MSXML 3.0, MSXML 4.0, and MSXML 5.0 the default **resolveExternals**
>   value is True. In MSXML 6.0, the default setting is False.
>
> If this property is set to False, no external includes and imports
>   will be resolved.

Is there a way around this that I am not seeing?  Normally I need the externals resolved, especially when dealing with XSDs or WSDLs.

Or am I fooling myself, and perhaps .resolveExternals never applies when using XMLHTTPRequest (only DOM.Load() calls)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
xmlhttp.responseXML.resolveExternals = true; 
xmlhttp.responseXML.setProperty("ProhibitDTD", false);
```

The only thing is the solution may only work with MSXML XMLHTTP ActiveX object.

Edit: here is a concrete sample with IE9:

```
var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
// var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET", "sample.xml", false);
xmlhttp.responseXML.async = false;
xmlhttp.responseXML.resolveExternals = true;
xmlhttp.responseXML.validateOnParse = false;
xmlhttp.responseXML.setProperty("ProhibitDTD", false);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
         alert(xmlhttp.responseXML.xml);
    }
}
xmlhttp.send();
```

sample.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE data SYSTEM "sample.dtd"><data>&ent;</data>
```

sample.dtd

```
<!ENTITY ent "Hello world!">
```

If you run the above cod with IE9, you'll successfully get the entity resolved. However, if you switch to the commented out XMLHttpRequest, you will fail.

PS: I thought you were talking about scripting inside IE, and there is a Trident native component called XMLHttpRequest which is quite different from XmlHttp ActiveX component. However, if you are referring to IXMLHttpRequest COM interface residing in MSXML6.DLL, you can translate the above code into C++ with ease.

Comment: The thing you call "MSXML XMLHTTP ActiveX object" is the same thing as an XMLHTTPRequest, I think you are getting its ProgId confused with its class name.  As far as I know you can't set a property on its .responseXML prior to actually doing a .send, and I believe that is (A) too late, and (B) if it works after the .send it may once again fail to use the credentials.

Comment: Hi Bob, I've edited the answer with a working sample. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Yes, I realize Trident had its own added later (IE7?).  Sorry I wasn't clearer about that.  It doesn't seem to have any effect, but I'll check more thoroughly.  If your event handler is working the rest should be too.  Thanks.

Comment: One hint is the onreadystatechange event is an IDispatch* in C++, instead of traditional COM connection point. http://www.ookii.org/post/using_ixmlhttprequestonreadystatechange_from_c.aspx has a working sample.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that pifall.  I assume it was done that way intentionally because of JavaScript's "event binding."  I was more concerned that the read-only .responseXML object might be created AFTER .send() though.